# Should you escape hardcoded URLs?

Tags: plugins, security, escaping

I'm writing a very simple social share plugin for a client. I'm using these two functions to display the share buttons at the bottom of each post:

```
<?php
/**
 * Social buttons
 */
function zss_share_buttons() {
?>
    <div class="zss">
        
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
            (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
        <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-layout="button_count" data-lazy="true"></div>
        
        <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;text=<?php echo urlencode( get_the_title() ); ?>" title="Share on Twitter" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" class="zss-button zss-button--twitter">Twitter</a>
        
        <a class="zss-button zss-button--linkedin" href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Share on LinkedIn" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">LinkedIn</a>
    
    </div>
<?php }

/**
 * Insert share button
 */ 
function zss_insert_share_buttons( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() && 'post' == get_post_type() ) {
        ob_start();
        zss_share_buttons();
        $content .= ob_get_clean();
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'zss_insert_share_buttons' );
```

Is it necessary to escape the hardcoded social media URLs with `esc_url()`? As I understand it, if the URL doesn't have an input via admin, it should be okay.

Comment: but it **does** have input, `the_permalink` and `get_the_title` are not hardcoded

Comment: Are these functions not already escaped by WordPress?

Comment: `the_permalink()` is. `get_the_permalink()` and `get_the_title()` are not.

Comment: Thank you. I'll esc those functions. I assume the hardcoded URLs are fine?

Comment: You should escape URLs, not fragments of URLs. Escape the entire URL as a whole. If the entire URL is hardcoded then you're fine, but if it has portions with non-hardcoded values then the entire thing needs to be escaped as one single unit. Your `the_permalink` calls are also problematic because they don't encode their output

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell, I'll look at escaping the whole URL. With the permalinks, why do these need to be encoded? In testing, the URLs share correctly.

Comment: If any of your permalinks contain a query string they'll break, there are other cases but that's the most obvious. It also means you have multiple escaping attempts for 1 URL. Escaping is all about enforcing expectations and assumptions. Why chance that it _"should"_ be a URL? You can guarantee it with `esc_url` and say that it is _"always"_ a URL. Enforce it! Remove all doubt! Use that cast iron guarantee

Comment: Thanks, @TomJNowell, that's super useful to know. Learnt a tonne today!

Comment: FYI to anyone who stumbles across this, the native Facebook data attribute `data-href` doesn't play well with encoded strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to escape hardcoded values.

> As I understand it, if the URL doesn't have an input via admin, it
> should be okay.

Not necessarily. There's many more potential sources of potentially malicious (or just accidentally broken) output that need to be accounted for, such as:

- Translations.
- Query strings ($_GET)
- Cookies.
- WordPress filters.

So generally you should escape any values output from most, if not all, functions and variables.

Comment: Ok. In some blogs I have seen that in order to follow the best practice, you have to escape all outputs without considering whether it is a hardcoded string or not. Do we really need that ?

Comment: I don't have anything to add other than what's in my answer. Do you have an example of anyone advising escaping hard-coded strings?

Comment: I don't have link to that with me now. I have seen such comments while searching for this topic the past few months (in Stack Overflow i think). But your answer is what most of the WordPress experts stick to. So i guess i will go with this answer.